# Not getting the current HTML page source while extracting HTML source of a web page

Tags: c#, .net, information-retrieval

I am using the below method to get the page source of a website . But the page source I am getting is not the current page source of the website . Any of you have any idea about why this is happening?

P.S. I am trying to get the page source of http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/

```
 public static string GetWebText(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "A .NET Web Crawler";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return htmlText;
    }
```

EDIT:
This is the part I'm bothered about section-id="featured-games"
The page-source for this section using the method mentioned earlier is as below:

```
    <section id="featured-games">
            <div class="blue-container">
                <div class="latest-games whitebox">
                    <div class="game-animation">
                        <div id="animation-rotator"></div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="games-list game-icons">
                                                <li data-animation="freerunning2" data-id="3798" id="animation-3798">
                            <div class="game-notification-container"><div class="game-notification"><div class="icon-new"></div><div class="game-notification-inner">New!</div></div></div><a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3798"  href="/games/free-running-2/en/#t-h-a"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/freerunning2V2.jpg" data-track="freerunning2V2" alt="Play Free Running2" title="Play Free Running 2" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Free Running2</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li data-animation="robotragenewarenav2" data-id="3491" id="animation-3491">
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3491"  href="/games/robot-rage/en/#t-h-a"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/3491-robot-13.png" data-track="3491-robot-13" alt="Play Robot Rage" title="Play Robot Rage" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Robot Rage</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li data-animation="penguinattack03" data-id="3748" id="animation-3748">
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3748"  href="/games/penguins-attack-iv/en/#t-h-a"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/penguinsattack4.jpg" data-track="penguinsattack4" alt="Play Pengu Attack" title="Play Penguins Attack IV" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Pengu Attack</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                            </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="hot-games whitebox">
                    <ul class="games-list game-icons">
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-1467"  href="/games/club-penguin/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/CP_starwars.jpg" data-track="CP_starwars" alt="Play Club Penguin" title="Play Club Penguin" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Club Penguin</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3814"  href="/games/summer-arcade/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/sony-arcade70x59-2.jpg" data-track="sony-arcade70x59-2" alt="Play Arcade" title="Play Summer Arcade" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Arcade</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3864"  href="/games/smurfette-vs-naughties/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/smurfettesmallicon.jpg" data-track="smurfettesmallicon" alt="Play Naughties" title="Play Naughties" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Naughties</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-2471"  href="/games/8-ball-pool-multiplayer/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/8ballpoolmultiplayerv7.jpg" data-track="8ballpoolmultiplayerv7" alt="Play 8 Ball Pool" title="Play 8 Ball Pool" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">8 Ball Pool</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-3800"  href="/games/scooby-doo-great-chase/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/scoobydoochasesmallicon.jpg" data-track="scoobydoochasesmallicon" alt="Play Great Chase" title="Play Great Chase" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Great Chase</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="game-icon small-icon game-id-2389"  href="/games/soccer-stars/en/#t-h-h"  title=""><span class="icon-wrap"><img src="//static2.miniclipcdn.com/content/game-icons/small/soccerstars.jpg" data-track="soccerstars" alt="Play Soccer Stars" title="Play Soccer Stars" width="68" height="57" /></span><span class="game-name">Soccer Stars</span>
</a>                        </li>
                                            </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- section#featured-games -->
```

Comment: show the html you get

Comment: If the page is composed with JavaScript (or async links) what you get is just its initial state. To get the full page you should execute JavaScript too (and it can't be done with HttpWebRequest). I would use a WebBrowserControl (even if it'll make everything slower).

Comment: @wudzik pls compare it with the current page source for the section..